# How can enable Fingerprint-GUI unlock/login/root access on Ubuntu17.10

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I have `Fingerprint-GUI` installed and it works sort of OK when I type `sudo` in terminal, but I cannot find a way to enable unlock/login or root access to settings using the fingerprint scanner. From what I found online it should just "be there" but it isn't

Comment: Is the `libpam-fprintd` package installed?

Comment: OK, this enabled me to do the login with fingerprint part, but I still can't find how to unlock screen with the fingerprint scanner...